# Microsoft Forefront TMG, IIS and SQL server on one server

Tags: firewall, microsoft-forefront

We have a Windows 2008 VPS with IIS and SQL Server, hosted by a provider. We use it for hosting web applications on the Internet. The only firewall we can use is Windows firewall. I would like to have more flexibility in the firewall configuration and logging. Is it possible to install Forefront TMG 2010 on the same server and use it just as a better firewall?

Thanks!

Comment: "The only firewall we can use is Windows firewall".  Windows firewall and Forefront are not the same.  It sounds like you have a conflict here, unless you mean you can use only a -Microsoft- firewall.  Will you be disabling the Windows firewall?  Also, do you realize that Forefront is a dead product?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant that our hosting provider does not offer an outside firewall. If we can move to Forefront, we will disable the Windows firewall. The dead product if OK for now, as our priority is the security of the server facing the Internet. I'm not sure if the Windows firewall is good enough for that (I am not an admin), so I am exploring Forefront, as we already have a license.   Another alternative is to move to a different hosting, with outside firewall.  Is Forefront a good alternative? All feedback will be greatly appreciated.